# Error in arrayShiftRight() function

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Ive got function that shifts array by 1 index to right:

```
void arrayShiftRight(int array[], int size) {
    int temp = array[size - 1];

    for ( int i = size; i > 0; i-- ) {
        array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }
    array[0] = array[temp];
}
```

the input is 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6

the output is
5 0 1 2 3 4 5

I can't understand why array[temp] becomes 5 instead of 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an off by one error, and `temp` is not an index, it's the stored value:

```
// i needs to start at size-1, not at size.
// Otherwise, you'd be writing past the end of the array.
for ( int i = size-1; i > 0; i-- ) {
    array[i] = array[i - 1];
}
array[0] = temp;
```

Comment: you're right, the array[temp] value is 6 and than it's changed to 5, now I see my mistake, thanx a lot.